# MDIParent designer screen is not loading

Tags: vb.net, winforms, wcf

When i try to view MDIParent screen in designer mode I’m getting below exception...

`Could not find endpoint element with name 'NetTcpBinding_IMyService' and contract 'ClientProxy.IMyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.'

Little background to understand my question more clearly...

I've a WCF server which I’m trying to consume in my Winform application. So i've created a separate class library in which i added service reference and created a proxy. I've copied the client endpoint info from app.config in class library to UI app.config file.

When i run the application everything is working fine but when i try to open MDIParent screen in designer mode its throwing above exception.

Note: I think i'm getting error because i'm trying to create a proxy object on NEW method (form constractor) if i comment that line - i'm able to view designer screen.

Please help :)

- Venky

Comment: Please post you config file and your service hosting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate the service in the form's constructor, this could be the source of your problem.

If this is the case, wrap the service initialization in a test for DesignMode:

```
    If Not Me.DesignMode Then
       ' Initialize service
    End If
```

**Update**

It turns out that DesignMode is [not supported in the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457).

There are a couple of workarounds to choose from:

1) Use the following instead of the designmode test:

```
If System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode <> System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime Then`
```

2) Move your initialization code from the constructor into the Form's _load event and then use the DesignMode test.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not Me.DesignMode Then
        ' Initialize service
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey - Thanks for your quick response.... I tried your suggestion still getting same exception :(

Comment: You are welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow! If the answer solves or helps you solve your question, be sure to click on the checkmark next to the answer so that future visitors to the question know that this is what solved your problem.

Comment: Did you rebuild the application after making this change?

Comment: Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Authentication/Authorization - CreateSession
        If Not Me.DesignMode Then
            _session.CreateSession()   '' service creation call
        End If

    End Sub

Comment: Do you have any properties or variables in the form that are defined as `New`? for example, `private m_Service as service = new service`?

Comment: not in form but in class library code when i'm creating a object of proxy

Comment: Ok, I figured out the issue: DesignMode is not supported in the form constructor. I have updated the answer with this info and some options.

Comment: Thank you very much buddy... :) your solution worked - I went with first option.